# Ramp Calculator: Beginning Output on Certian Row Based on Start Date + Repeating Monthly Volume Once Ramp = 100%

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lagB1AtjlPByRR9OUWbeJlVfJbWoQHSi/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106060891313761840163&rtpof=true&sd=true

I need some help with a project I am working on that is basically a volume ramp-up calculator / tracker. I have tried so many different formulas and can not get it to work the way I would like. Looking for any and all suggestions and thank you in advance for any ideas! There are two things: 1.) I need the output to start on a certain row based on the Start Date selected and 2.) I need the full Monthly Volume to repeat on the output table once Ramp Up is = 100%.

**Inputs by User**

[image: Example User Inputs]

***Fields***

Start Date - User can choose Jan-22 through Dec-25 from the drop-down list (done)

Yearly Target Volume - User can enter any amount here for the volume of queries

Month 1-8 ramp up (% of Monthly Volume) - User can enter any amount here (%) as long as it = 100% - ***Used for Output Calculation***

Ramp-up % sum (test) - Automatically calculated for good measure so the user knows their ramp-up = 100%

Quarterly Volume - Automatically calculated for reference

Monthly Volume - Automatically calculated for reference but **used for output calculation**

**Example Output for James and Owen - This is the Output Table That Never Is Edited**

[image: Example User Output]

**What Happened?**

1. User James and User Owen are already pre-populated because it is referencing cells C2 and D2 (etc. - ignore)

**How is the output table calculated?**

***User James***

1. Start Date = "May-22" = Start Column E Row 26

- Leave Jan-22 through Apr-22 blank - it is okay if there is a "0" or "-" in Jan-22 through Apr-22

***This portion here I am struggling with: How do I get the data to match the start date inputted by the user with the start dates in rows 22 through 69 and begin on that specific row?***

3. Multiply Monthly Volume * Month 1 ramp up % (Column C Row 17 x Column C row 6)
4. Follow this process - continue to calculate Monthly Volume X Specified Month 2.3.4.5... Ramp up % until the sum of them (or the sum of the outputs) is = 100% of Monthly Volume.
5. Once you reach 100% - input Monthly volume in the remaining rows until Dec-25

***I am struggling here: the formulas I have tried keep calculating down through row 15-17 and doesn't stop. How do I get the formula to stop and repeat 100% of the monthly volume for the remaining rows? I need a way for the formula to continue multiplying Month Ramp-up % by Monthly Volume until the sum of outputs is = monthly volume and then repeat the monthly volume for the remaining cells.***

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly....

```
Sub test()
Dim dtStart As Date, dtEnd As Date, dtMid As Date, dif As Integer
Dim rg1 As Range, rg2 As Range, cell As Range, c As Range

dtStart = "1-Jan-22": dtEnd = "1-Dec-25"

With ActiveSheet
    Set rg1 = .Range("C3", .Range("c3").End(xlToRight)) 'change if needed
    Set rg2 = .Range("e21", .Range("e21").End(xlToRight)) 'change if needed
End With

    For Each cell In rg1
        Set c = rg2.Find(cell.Offset(-1, 0))
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            dif = DateDiff("m", dtStart, cell.Value) + 1
            c.Offset(dif, 0).Resize(cell.Offset(2, 0).Value, 1).Value = _
                "=" & Cells(17, cell.Column).Address & "*" & cell.Offset(3, 0).Address(0, 0)
            
            Set LastCell = c.Offset(cell.Offset(2, 0).Value + dif, 0)
            LastCell.Value = _
                "=" & Cells(17, cell.Column).Address & "*" & Cells(15, cell.Column).Address(0, 0)
            
            dtMid = DateAdd("m", cell.Offset(2, 0).Value + 1, cell.Value)
            LastCell.Offset(1, 0).Resize(DateDiff("m", dtMid, dtEnd) + 1, 1).Value = "=" & LastCell.Address
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

dtStart variable is the starting date as seen in cell C22, which is "1 Jan 22" and dtEnd is "1 Dec 25".

It set a range as rg1 starting from c3 to end right, and set range as rg2 starting from e21 to end right.

then it loop to each cell in rg1, and set c as a range where the looped cell offset(-1,0) value (the name) is found in rg2.

If the name is found in rg2, it make dif variable as month difference between dtStart and the looped cell value + 1 (in this case example, the first iteration of the looped cell value is 1-May-22 and the dif result is 5).

So the dif will be used to offset from c as the beginning cell which contain the formula, and it resize the row by using the looped cell offset(2,0) value (in this case example, the first iteration is 6), then it fill with the formula (in this case example, the first iteration formula is `$C$17*C6`.

The process for the rest of the row until 1-Dec-25, almost the same.

Step run the macro.
On each variable or command which is a range, insert a "select" code to check.

Example :
add `rg1.select: rg2.select` after the variable is set.
add `c.select` after c is set.
see the Locals window, what is the value of dif in `dif = DateDiff("m", dtStart, cell.Value) + 1`

add `cell.select` right after `for each cell in rg1`

add `c.Offset(dif, 0).Resize(cell.Offset(2, 0).Value, 1).select` BEFORE `c.Offset(dif, 0).Resize(cell.Offset(2, 0).Value, 1).value=....`

add `debug.print "=" & Cells(17, cell.Column).Address & "*" & cell.Offset(3, 0).Address(0, 0)` to see if the formula is correct

add `LastCell.select` after the LastCell is set.
See the Locals window, what is the value result of dtMid.
and so on.

[image]

Comment: Hi Karma - wow! I appreciate the help here. Having trouble getting the macro to run and produce an output. Let me continue trying

Comment: I don't use VBA much so please forgive me: To get this to work, I add the above as a module to the sheet and run the macro and it should be populating data in the table? Are you able to get it to populate on your end? Thank you!

Comment: The logic makes perfect sense - genius! I just can't get the macro to produce an output in the table when I run it.

Comment: Please have a look as I add more code for the rest of the row until 1-Dec-25. I've downloaded your sample workbook and test the code with the data. It work as expected. Please note, the code assumed (before running the sub) that cell C21:D69 already there and also the name in E21 and E22 already there. Please step run the macro to see what happen. To check a range variable, you can try to add a code to select to see what happen (and later on remove it) ---> something like : `c.Offset(dif, 0).Resize(cell.Offset(2, 0).Value, 1).select`. See also the Locals window for dif and dtMid value.

Comment: Perfect - Hmmmm., I can't get it to populate anything (the 20.883, 83.33, 145.83) in the bottom table when running. You don't have any formulas in Cells E22 through E69 right? As long as there is data in cells C3-C13 and I run the macro, it should be producing a result

Comment: Please see above picture in the post "Output When Running Below Macro @karma"

Comment: In your sample workbook, I delete all value from cell E22:F69. So those range is empty then I run the macro.

Comment: Interesting - I don't know what I could be doing wrong. I run the macro and nothing happens :( You have provided a lot here though so I am determined to get it to run and produce an output

Comment: Please don't just directly run it, but step run it. I add some instruction to check the code line by line while step run the code.

Comment: I apologize but I do not have the technical ability to do the above. I was just tryign to run the above code that you provided. I was just looking for a solution to provide the table output by entering data in cells C3-C13 and in the future people will continue to enter data (start date, yearly target, etc.) and re-run the macro. Greatly appreciate all this though and will reach out to a friend for his technical background.

Comment: Absolute genius! Thank you so much. The problem was, my cell E21 was a formula referencing cell c2!! Once I changed that to just User James as text, it worked